# Get PictureBox Name

Tags: c#

I have 2 PictureBox , name: pictureBox1, pictureBox2 
how i can get the name of pictureBox that i clicked on it?

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("clicked on: " + ??????);
    }
    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("clicked on: " + ???????);
    }
```

Comment: if each picturebox has it's own click handler, you can just assume that the clicked picturebox in picturebox1_click(..){} was pictureBox1, vice versa

Comment: @cppanda that would solve his problem in this example, but it's not a neat way to do it. I suggest usign Vloxxity's answer

Comment: you have to use an event like that event MouseButtonEventHandler MouseLeftButtonDown
and that gives you the the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void PictureBoxesClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is PictureBox)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("clicked on: " + ((PictureBox)sender).Name);
    }
}
```

And with this code you don't need 2 `events`, you can use one event for both `pictureboxes`.

Comment: Since this is a basic question, maybe you want to explain why this works. Good answer though ;)

Comment: hi Vloxxity, how can use one event for both pictureboxes? i tried add a mouseclick event in form1

Comment: i guess you are using visual studio..
1.Open the DesignView of the Form
2.Mark all Pictureboxes and then go to the Properties window select the event Tab and set the Click event (with typing the name or selecting it out of the combobox) or create a new one with double clicking the name of the event

Comment: so you dont need a mouseclick event on the form you can use the pictureBox1_Click you already got just assign it to the othe rboxes too...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String text;
    text=PictureBox1.Text;
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked on:"+text);
}
```